# VB6 DAO 3.51 suddenly has errors (Error 91, file not found)

Tags: vb6, dao, jet

Our VB6 program has worked for many years at multiple sites without problem. In recent weeks some users have been experiencing unexpected, apparently random, file access issues. The include Error 91, file not found, file in use.

The program uses DAO 3.51 to access Access .mdb and FoxPro .dbf (via msxbse35.dll) files. The errors seem to have occurred with both these, although only *some* sites have reported issues.

This has happened to sites using Windows 7 and 10, where our installed code has not changed. I suspect a recent change within Windows.

Though DAO is officially no longer supported, it has worked for years. Does anyone have ideas to solve this problem?

I would like to be able to preserve our source code, with at most minor changes. Rewriting the code for ADO would be prohibitive, as would moving to VB.NET.

Comment: Do you know what file is not being found?

Comment: I don't know about file not found errors but I've experienced lots of problems after Office365 users have opened an Access 2000 or 2010 database. Have the affected sites installed any new versions of Office?